# Bash Script reporting members of a group

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I need to be able to create a script using bash that will report the members of a specific group (users are in this group), write the output to a file and use crontab to schedule the script

I have done the Crontab part but not sure if that is also correct:

```
 - 5:55am: 55 5 * * 1-5 /bin/sh /home/test/membersofgroup.sh 
 - 9:55am: 55 9 * * 1-5 /bin/sh /home/test/membersofgroup.sh
 - 3:55pm: 55 15 * * 1-5 /bin/sh /home/test/membersofgroup.sh
```

Regards.

Comment: I assume `- 5:55am:` isn't actually in the crontab, you just used that here for explanation. If that's correct, then what you have looks correct. But SO isn't the appropriate place to ask for help with `crontab`, unix.stackexchange.com is a better place.

Comment: You can combine them into a single line: `55 5,9,15 * * 1-5 /bin/sh /home/tycho/membersofgroup.sh`

Comment: You can list the users with: `awk -F\: '/^specific:/ {print $4}' /etc/group > file.txt`. Output will be like: `user1,user2,user3 ...`.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for that!

I will head over to unix.stackexchange.com and ask there as well.

Comment: @JamesBrown so i add that to a .sh file?

Comment: @l2script I don't know what else your script does but if it just lists users and appends them to a file see my answer below (I just fixed the crontab every-minute-execution to match your requirement).

Answer (score 0):

Combining @Barmar's `crontab` entry with my `awk`:

```
$ cat >> crontab_file_of_yours.txt
55 5,9,15 * * 1-5 awk -F\: '/^specific:/ && $0=$4' /etc/group >> /pathto/file.txt
$ crontab crontab_file_of_yours.txt
```